# JSON Request in body html

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an https.request to an API server. I can receive the chunk(JSON) and print it in the console. How can I write it directly into html and show it in the browser?

```
var requestListener = function (req, res) {

    var db = admin.database(); 
    var ref = db.ref("Clubs"); 
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) { 

   console.log(snapshot.val());     //print on console

       res.write( snapshot.val() ); // in body html, error       throw er;                               
       // Unhandled 'error' event ^Error: write after end

    }, function (errorObject) {         
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);

    });

// CRUD

    ref.child("club1").set({
        clubId: 1,
        clubName: "club1",
        telephone: "6548798",
        address: "Lviv",
        party: "qwe,asd,zxc"
    });

    ref.child("club2").set({
        clubId: 2,
        clubName: "club2",
        telephone: "234234",
        address: "Kiev",
        party: "qwe,zxc"
    });    
    res.end();
};

var server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: You have to stringify the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `res.end()` at the end of the `requestListener`. But it's called just after 'defining' the database read handler. So when your db triggers the 'value' event for the first time, it is too late to send data on HTTP response.

To fix it, you need to move `res.end();` to the point where database finishes pushing its data. There should be a `close` or `end` event depending on the db/adapter your are using. If not, then the right place would be just after the `.write()` if this is guaranteed to be a one time only call 'value' event.